# choose month according to number of date he has been hired

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

suppose that in oracle 11.g   database,we are trying to add new  employeer,in case of we hired(let's say so)  in  any day  less then 15  of current month,then we write hiredate  for  him as a current month  ,otherwise next month,
for example  suppose  that now is  december,if when i have hired   new employee was less then 15 december ,then it's hire month will be same december,but in case of  more then 15 ,for example 15,16, and so on,then  his hire_month will be january,how can i determine   whose employees are  hired in more then 15  in each month?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ROUND function, like this:

```
select round(<yourdate>, 'MONTH') hire_month from dual
```

Comment: Round only rounds up on the 16th day of the month, the OP needs it to round up on the 15th.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT (CASE 
           WHEN EXTRACT(day FROM hiredate) < 15
           THEN EXTRACT(month FROM hiredate)
           ELSE (EXTRACT(month FROM hiredate) + 1)
         END) AS HireMonth
  FROM employee
 WHERE empno = <your number>
```

If you want the month by name then:

```
SELECT (CASE 
           WHEN EXTRACT(day FROM hiredate) < 15
           THEN TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'Month')
           ELSE TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, 1), 'Month')
         END) AS HireMonth
  FROM employee
 WHERE empno = <your number>
```

EDIT: As you can't use CASE then here is an alternative (though it is far better to use [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'Month') AS hireMonth
  FROM employee
 WHERE EXTRACT(day FROM hiredate) < 15
   AND empno = <your number>
 UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, 1), 'Month') AS hireMonth
  FROM employee
 WHERE EXTRACT(day FROM hiredate) >= 15
   AND empno = <your number>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: yes it would be  fine but i have not study  still here   case and if-else i need it for midterm

Comment: @Dato, I don't understand your comment. What do you need?

Comment: i  said that i have not  studed  case and  if-else  function yet,can i do same without use these functions

Answer (score 1):

look up Oracle's to_char function. This will allow you to pull specific values out of a date.

to_char(data_value,'DD') will give you the day of the month for example.